# Invalid cross-thread access in GeocodeQuery on Windows Phone

Tags: c#, multithreading, windows-phone-8, geolocation

I'm developing for WP8 and have the following code

```
public static async Task<GeoCoordinate> ConvertToGeoCoordinate(String streetAddress)
{
    // NOTE: constructor throws invalid cross thread exception
    var query = new GeocodeQuery()
    {
        GeoCoordinate = new GeoCoordinate(0, 0),
        SearchTerm = streetAddress,
        MaxResultCount = 1,
    };

    var task = new TaskCompletionSource<GeoCoordinate>();
    query.QueryCompleted += (s, ev) =>
    {
        foreach (var item in ev.Result)
            task.TrySetResult(item.GeoCoordinate);

        task.TrySetResult(null);
    };
    query.QueryAsync();

    return await task.Task;
}
```

I'm not that familiar with tasks, async, await and stuff but I'm pretty sure the call `var res = await ConvertToGeoCoordinate("blabla");` should not return an invalid cross-thread access. Somewhere in the internet I ran across a guy who said that GeocodeQuery needs to be executed on the UI thread but if I call `ConvertToGeoCoordinate("blabla").ContinueWith((x) => {Log(x.Result.ToString();});` I get a result and this is no synchronous execution.

Currently I'm doing stuff like this (because it works)

```
ConvertToGeoCoordinate(addr1).ContinueWith(() => {
    ConvertToGeoCoordinate(addr2).ContinueWith(() => {
        ConvertToGeoCoordinate(addr2).ContinueWith(() => {
            ...
        });
    });
});
```

instead of (because it works not)

```
await ConvertToGeoCoordinate(addr1);
await ConvertToGeoCoordinate(addr2);
await ConvertToGeoCoordinate(addr3);
...
```

and this is awkward. How do I do it right with GeocodeQuery? Has anyone some experience with that?

Comment: But if you use the second form -- `ConvertToGeoCoordinate(addr1).ContinueWith(()` -- then that does not actually execute on a background thread ... right?  Seems like the random guy on the internet was correct.

Comment: I believe it only looks synchronous, but it's really an async operation. Honestly, I don't know...anyway is there any fix known for this issue? I did not find anything and I don't want the GUI to be blocked and the code to be THAT ugly...

Comment: I don't know, but did you try putting just the `new GeocodeQuery` instantiation on the UI thread?  I'd be surprised if the "QueryAsync" part itself needed to be UI-bound.

Comment: You are settings the result multiple times, it think that in combination with the thread marshaling of the await keyword could cause your exception. TrySetResult does not return, so try: if(tcs.TrySetResult(...)) return;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*GeocodeQuery* can only be created on the main/UI thread. Make sure you are calling your ConvertoToGeocoordinate method only from the main/UI thread.

You could for example use the dispatcher:

```
Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(async() => { ... });
```

(I tried your exact code and it works fine with await when called from the UI thread.)